# Why is the CPU slower for calculations then the GPU when only Memory should matter?

Tags: algorithm, performance, gpu

A modern CPU has a ethash hashrate from under 1MH/s (source: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2325/is-cpu-mining-even-worth-the-ether ) while GPUs mine with over 20MH/s easily. With overclocked memory they reach rates up to 30MH/s.

GPUs have GDDR Memory with Clockrates of about 1000MHz while DDR4 runs with higher clock speeds. Bandwith of DDR4 seems also to be higher (sources: http://www.corsair.com/en-eu/blog/2014/september/ddr3_vs_ddr4_synthetic and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GDDR5_SDRAM )

It is said for Dagger-Hashimoto/ethash bandwith of memory is the thing that matters (also experienced from overclocking GPUs) which I find reasonable since the CPU/GPU only has to do 2x sha3 (1x Keccak256 + 1x Keccak512) operations (source: https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethash#main-loop ).

A modern Skylake processor can compute over 100M of Keccak512 operations per second (see here: https://www.cryptopp.com/benchmarks.html ) so then core count difference between GPUs and CPUs should not be the problem.

But why don't we get about ~50Mhash/s from 2xKeccak operations and memory loading on a CPU?

Comment: A GPU has more processor cores.

Comment: I know this but the algorithm don't reliant on processing performance as I understood because there where only 2 sha3 calls which an modern processor is able to handle a lot faster than 1M times / s

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are GPUs more powerful than CPUs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6435428/why-are-gpus-more-powerful-than-cpus)

Comment: No it's no duplicate I know that GPUs have more cores. This algorithm is designed to have it's bottelneck on memory but i din't found anything why the Memory is the bottelneck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an article addressing my problem (the influence of Memory on the algorithm).

It's not only the computation problem (mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48687460/2298744 ) it's also the Memorybandwidth which would bottelneck the CPU.

As described in the article every round fetches 8kb of data for calculation. This results in the following formular:

> (Memory Bandwidth) / ( DAG memory fetched per hash) = Max Theoreticical Hashrate
>
> (Memory Bandwidth) / ( 8kb / hash) = Max Theoreticical Hashrate

For a grafics card like the RX470 mentioned this results in:

> (211 Gigabytes / sec) / (8 kilobytes / hash) = ~26Mhashes/sec

While for CPUs with DDR4 this will result in:

> (12.8GB / sec) / (8 kilobytes / hash) = ~1.6Mhashes/sec

or (debending on clock speeds of RAM)

> (25.6GB / sec) / (8 kilobytes / hash) = ~3.2Mhashes/sec

To sum up, a CPU or also GPU with DDR4 ram could not get more than 3.2MHash/s since it can't get the data fast enough needed for processing.

Source:

https://www.vijaypradeep.com/blog/2017-04-28-ethereums-memory-hardness-explained/

Answer (score 2):

See http://www.nvidia.com/object/what-is-gpu-computing.html for an overview of the differences between CPU and GPU programming.

In short, a CPU has a very small number of cores, each of which can do different things, and each of which can handle very complex logic.

A GPU has thousands of cores, that operate pretty much in lockstep, but can only handle simple logic.

Therefore the overall processing throughput of a GPU can be massively higher.  But it isn't easy to move logic from the CPU to the GPU.

If you want to dive in deeper and actually write code for both, one good starting place is https://devblogs.nvidia.com/gpu-computing-julia-programming-language/.

Answer (score 2):

"A modern Skylake processor can compute over 100M of Keccak512 operations per second" is incorrect, it is 140 **MiB/s**. That is MiBs per second and a hash operation is more than 1 byte, you need to divide the 140 MiB/s by the number of bytes being hashed.

Comment: This would mean 140 / 508 = 0.2755 Mhash/s; This matches the observed values pretty good; Size taken form here:
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13017/how-large-are-the-ethereum-block-headers